# Wine 64-bit crashes in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wine, crash

[image]

I'm getting such crash after playing wined old windows games on Ubuntu 20.04 as shown in a screenshot. I don't know reason it crashing. Dependencies have huge list on this one (not shown in a screenshot). How to make work without a crash ? Is it normal ?

Comment: What errors about wine are at your syslogs ?